# How change the resolution without reload the whole Video?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vimeo

When using Vimeo's unity sdk there is a parameter that defines the resolution of the video currently playing.
To change that, I need to set the desired resolution and call the method `LoadVideo()` on Vimeo sdk to take effect.
But, when I call load video just for the sake of changing the Resolution,the video starts playing from the beginning and not from the current time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [`For questions and support, ask on StackOverflow.`](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk#questions-help-and-support) lol .. that's kind of the laziest support I've ever seen ^^ Unfortunately for us it is kind of impossible to help here without seeing your code and knowing anything about the SDK and its API. I guess you rather should ask the makers of the SDK instead or provide more information like example code here

Comment: We need additional information to troubleshoot, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask